# Замена значений в списке python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужна помощь!
Нужно сделать функцию, которая бы в листе

```
winner = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [3, 6, 9],
    [1, 5, 9],
    [3, 5, 7]
]

def replace(list, number):
    for i in winner[[]]:
        i = "X"
```

заменяла каждую одинаковую  цифру  целом списке на нужное мне значение.

Добавил кусок кода (игра крестики нолики)

Comment: Покажите ваш код, покажите где и как он работает неправильно.

Comment: Одинаковость - это не свойство какой-то отдельно взятой цифры. При таком критерии замены работать нужно сразу с группой цифр.

Comment: а как например заменить все единицы допустим на значение "X"?

Comment: Вас уже просили привести кусок кода. Настоятельно рекомендую выполнить эту рекомендацию. Если конечно хотите получить качественный ответ

Comment: Вот так: `map(lambda y: ['X' if x == 1 else x for x in y], winner)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def replace(lst, number):
    for row in lst:
        for i, val in enumerate(row):
            if val == number:
                row[i] = 'X'
    return lst

winner = [ [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 7], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7] ]
print(replace(winner, 1))

>>>
[['X', 2, 3], ['X', 4, 7], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], ['X', 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]]
```